# Create a function type template in Typescript

Tags: typescript, typeof

I have a function that's something like the following except much less simple:

```
function foo(arg1?: string | number | boolean, arg2?: number | boolean, arg3?: boolean) {
  // omitted
}
```

This function can be ran many different ways, for example:

```
foo();
foo(1, true);
foo("", false);
foo(4);
foo(true);
// ..etc
```

In order to make context clues / type definitions readable, the best way is with overloads:

```
function foo();
function foo(name: string);
function foo(age: number);
function foo(nice: boolean);
function foo(name: string, age: number);
function foo(name: string, nice: boolean);
function foo(age: number, nice: boolean);
function foo(name: string; age: number, nice: boolean);
function foo(arg1?: string | number | boolean, arg2?: number | boolean, arg3?: boolean) {
  // omitted
}

// now it'll figure out which overload I'm on, and give easier to read insights
```

The *issue* is that I don't just have foo.  I have foo, bar, qux, baz, and 30 others.  It would be a terrible wall of text to write it all.  So I tried making one type for all, and it would work if it wasn't for generics:

```
// Without generics, this problem would be solved

export const bar = (function(...args: ArgOutline) {
  // omitted
}) as typeof foo

export const qux = (function(...args: ArgOutline) {
  // omitted
}) as typeof foo

export const baz = (function(...args: ArgOutline) {
  // omitted
}) as typeof foo

/// and so on...
```

---

What I really want is an outline function which takes generics and can produce something that has readable insights, but the following code does not work:

```
function Outline();
function Outline(name: string);
function Outline<PROPS>(props: PROPS);
function Outline(name: string props: PROPS);
function Outline<PROPS>(arg1?: string | PROPS, arg2?: PROPS) {
  // omitted
}


// This doesn't work
export const baz = (function(...args: ArgOutline) {
  // omitted
}) as typeof Outline<{a: number}>
```

I've read on why you can't do this (https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/204), but it still seems there is a way, just not this way.

How can I make a generic type which will produce insights that say `(+N overloads)` rather than `() => ReallyTerriblyLongName | (name: string) => ReallyTerriblyLongName | (name: string, props: AlsoATerriblyLongName) => ReallyTerriblyLongName | ...etc`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try interface (I'm assuming your return type is void):

```
interface Outline {
    (): void;
    (name: string): void;
    <PROPS>(props: PROPS): void;
    <PROPS>(name: string, props: PROPS): void;
}

export const bar = function(...args: any[]) { } as Outline;
```

You can also move the generic argument to the interface itself:

```
interface Outline<PROPS> {
    (): void;
    (name: string): void;
    (props: PROPS): void;
    (name: string, props: PROPS): void;
}

export const bar = function(...args: any[]) { } as Outline<{ a: number }>;
```

Answer (score 0):

Literally climbed out of bed for this one.

```
function Outline<PROPS>() {

  function out();
  function out(name: string);
  function out(props: PROPS);
  function out(name: string props: PROPS);
  function out(arg1?: string | PROPS, arg2?: PROPS) {
    // omitted
  }

  return out;
}

// Create the outline, then get its type
const bazOutline = Outline<{a: number}>();
export const baz = (function(...args: ArgOutline) {
  // omitted
}) as typeof bazOutline
```

Create a function that returns a function of the type you want.  Then get typeof from that... still need to test in the wild, but I'm getting proper type defs right now.  Maybe exports will break.